# Absence of a Review option in mobile view

Tags: feature-request, review, mobile-web

There is no Review option on mobile view of websites. Below is the screenshot of the page as I see from mobile view of Physics Stack Exchange.

[image]

As you can see, there is no Review tab, while there is one in the desktop version:

[image]

It's difficult to always change to the desktop version for editing, and hence, I feel a Review tab must be incorporated in the mobile view to allow quick access.